# Match first 4 characters in a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am using python and regex. I read the file using python and I want to remove some of the words/characters from the file. I am using `re.sub()`. This is an example of what the strings look like:

```
Proxy BR 1.05s [HTTPS] 200.203.144.2:50262
```

I managed to remove the words and all the special characters, leaving, for example,

```
1.20 187.94.217.693128
```

but I cannot get rid of the first 4 characters. which are `1.05`.

This is my regex:

```
pattern = "[a-zA-Z\[\],:<>]"
```

How can I get the first 4 characters to be removed?

Comment: Aren't the first 4 characters `'Prox'`?

Comment: well i did remove the letters as you can see in the example i showed, but im stuck with:  1.20    187.94.217.693128 after i remove the letters and the special characters

Comment: `s.rsplit()[-1]`? See https://ideone.com/WSejdv

Comment: what if it takes 12.05s to run?

Comment: Ok, it seems that i forgot to mention that i am not trying to target only that specific string, the file that im reading contains multiple rows of strings like that one.

Comment: Then, let me clarify. Is the only thing that you want to do right now is to *remove the first four characters from every line in the file*?

Comment: So what im trying to do is to remove from the file everything except the 200.203.144.2:50262(which is the proxy). What i have done so far was to remove the letters and the special characters, but that leaves me with the time(1.05s) and the proxy. Is this more understandable ?

Comment: It is. This actually sounds more like an XY problem, because as @Matthew0898 has mentioned, removing the first four characters will not always get you what you want.

Comment: The time is part of the string, it tells how much time it takes for the proxy to respond

Comment: Yes, so what if the time is over 10 seconds?

Comment: Please post your code--or rather, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MVCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it.

Comment: @MathieuK. Here is my code: https://imgur.com/2NQoE4c

Comment: @GabrielMatei posting your code as an image is not the prefer way on Stack Overflow.  I looked at your code, but what we need are more examples from the input file - myproxy.txt.   I noted in your question comments that you only want the ip_address:port_number section of the string.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex yes, that is correct. This is how the input from myproxy.txt looks like: 
  <Proxy US 0.16s [HTTP: High, HTTPS] 104.248.168.64:3128>
<Proxy US 0.20s [HTTP: High, HTTPS] 54.81.69.91:3128>
<Proxy LT 0.77s [HTTP: High, HTTPS] 78.60.130.181:30664>
<Proxy AT 0.85s [HTTP: High] 80.120.86.242:46771>
<Proxy RU 0.51s [HTTP: High] 109.74.135.246:45769>
<Proxy CA 1.19s [HTTP: High, HTTPS] 198.50.172.161:1080>
<Proxy IN 1.26s [HTTP: High] 103.250.166.12:47031>
<Proxy TR 0.79s [HTTP: Transparent, HTTPS] 88.255.101.244:8080>

Comment: @GabrielMatei  I updated my answer to use myproxy.txt.  Let me know if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below only looks for the IPv4 address and port number in the input string.  The format for an IP address and port number combination is:

> digit{1,3}.digit{1,3}.digit{1,3}.digit{1,3}:digit{1,5}

```
import re

with open('myproxy.txt', 'r') as input:
  lines = input.readlines()
  pattern_to_find = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5})')

  for line in lines:
    find_pattern = re.search(pattern_to_find, line)
    if find_pattern:
        print(find_pattern.group())
        # outputs 
        104.248.168.64:3128
        54.81.69.91:3128
        78.60.130.181:30664
        80.120.86.242:46771
        109.74.135.246:45769
        198.50.172.161:1080
        103.250.166.12:47031
        88.255.101.244:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an *anchor* (`^` represents the start of the string, and `.{4}` any four characters after that):

```
import re

re.sub('^.{4}', '', '1.20 187.94.217.693128')
```

Output:

```
' 187.94.217.693128'
```

Comment: If you run the code exactly as it is, it will work, on the given string.

Comment: How can i make it run on every string in the file, because there are more stings like that one in the file im reading from.

Comment: @GabrielMatei Then your question should be "How do I get the IP:port from every line in this file" with an example of the file and your current code.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen Yes, sorry for formulating the question wrong, but i thought i was close to doing it myself and i only needed to remove the time because i managed to remove the letters and special characters myself